# Can we have infinite TTL for AWS DAX item cache?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I've currently set the item cache TTL for my DAX cluster as 0. I can't find any good documentation for an infinite timeout. But does that correspond to an infinite timeout?

```
 ParameterNameValues:
        "query-ttl-millis" : "60000"
        "record-ttl-millis" : "0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, setting "record-ttl-millis" to "0" means that DAX will never refresh a value based on TTL. Records can still be evicted (and thus refreshed on next request) if the cache fills up.

I'll see about clearing up the documentation on TTL to make this clear.

Comment: @ Jeff:  what's the source of this `record-ttl-millis=0` tip? I wasn't able to find anywhere in docs that AWS supports 0 value here. Have you tried it?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.cluster-management.html#DAX.cluster-management.custom-settings.ttl here is an example of increased item cache TTL but it's not infinite.

Comment: That's how it was implemented back when I worked on it. I don't know if that's still case if it was never documented.